# catkin_make ignores dependencies?

Tags: ros, catkin-make, package.xml, dependencies, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure what's causing this but catkin_make ignores dependencies for one or two of my packages.

The package `x_competitor_layer` depends on the message generation of `x_eth_interface`. I've added this dependency in

- package.xml (build_depend and run_depend)
- CMakeLists.txt (`x_eth_interface` in `find_package` as well as `x_eth_interface_generate_messages` in `add_dependencies`)

of `x_competitor_layer` package.

But still catkin_make doesn't build `x_eth_interface_generate_messages` first and keeps complaining about a missing header file. I can solve this problem manually by calling catkin_make x_eth_interface_generate_messages first. But catkin should be able to solve it on its own, shouldn't it?

So what could possibly have gone wrong? What might be missing?

Thanks guys!

Cheers,
Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94516/catkin_make-ignores-dependencies?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2013-10-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-10-26**:
Maybe it's a different problem, but have you tried to call catkin_make, a few times in row?

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-10-26**:
Yepp, I have. Sadly to no avail.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-10-27**:
Please provide a minimal rosinstall file for your workspace (or point to repos containing the code in question) which allows to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Difficult to tell what goes wrong without seeing the actual cmake code of x_competitor_layer. Check for typos.

Note that it should be preferable not to refer to implicit targets anymore, as discussed here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ros-sig-buildsystem/dvVO5QCHBLM/gJpUcUWYHt0J

I realize nobody updated the docs though ( https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/547 ).

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-10-30**:
Hmm, I'm afraid, I don't really get it, because I don't have that much of an insight into the guts of ROS, yet. I guess, the best for me is to stick with the unresolved dependencies for the time being and solve them manually whenever recompiling comes necessary.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-11-03**:
This is not much about ROS, but mostly about cmake. Possibly you made a typo in find_dependencies, or used it on the wrong target, or missed a target, etc. The possibilities are endless, if you want help, paste the error log and the CMakeLists.txt